# UK Land Registry plan confusion

Tags: planning

I'm in the process of buying a property, I've just received the land registry plan from the solicitors and I'm confused as to what the grey line through the property is. Also why the bounds of the property extend over the road.

Anyone have any ideas? (Couldn't find a more appropriate stack to post this to - sorry if its not as relevant as most questions!)

[image]

Comment: The road may be a private road that's yours to maintain. For the gray line, maybe a utility right of way, or storm water drainage, probably best to ask those that are selling the property.

Comment: Thanks, the house is currently owned by an elderly lady who doesn't know, her recently deceased husband dealt with everything. I'm getting on to the council seeing what they can tell me.

Comment: The gray area is probably described and explained in the deeds. It may be  something to do with underground services to that rectangular building adjacent to *arland avenue. It looks like the road might be unadopted - in which case the local council isn't responsible for maintaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Unusual that the grey is just on your property. If its utility based I'd expect to see it run through the whole plan.

The road as mentioned is probably unadopted and although it indicates that you're responsible for the section outlined, in practice these roads are often work as 'shared' ownership and the cost of work on it would be shared out between all that use it for access to their properties.

Comment: Thank,s we're told we'll find out more soon from the solicitors. From the many opinions we've had, everyone seems to think unadopted, but we'll see!